# Does "leaving many unemployed, furloughed or working reduced hours" modify "the global jobs market"?

Tags: grammar

The coronavirus pandemic has wreaked havoc on the global jobs market, ***leaving many unemployed, furloughed or working reduced hours*** as employers implemented sweeping cost-cutting measures.

"leaving many unemployed, furloughed or working reduced hours" is like an adjective to modify "the global jobs market"?

Answer (score 1):

Functionally, it's an adverbial phrase modfiying the main-clause predicate "wreaked havoc on the global jobs market" and introduces the consequence of the action.

Comment: I'd prefer to call it a gerund-participial clause (not a phrase) functioning as an adjunct in clause structure, where the adjunct indicates a resultant situation. It's more of a supplement than a modifier.